# What is the best way to know if a response in JSON is null in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, httparty, rails-api

I'm building an API on Rails for an app on Rails too, for the authentication I'm using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and on the side of the application that uses the API I'm using [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), devise_token_auth have a `current_user` method which returns the user if it is logged in or nil otherwise, so what I want is to see on the side of the application that uses the API if a user is logged on there, for this I wonder what is the best way to check if a response in JSON is null.

This is part of what I get when I use the inspect method on the object that get the value returned by the request from HTTParty to the API.

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x10 parsed_response=nil, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["Cowboy"], "date"=>["Wed, 30 Dec 2015 15:13:22 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"] blah... blah... blah...
```

**P.S**: For now if I check if the length of the response in JSON is equal to 0 I can determine if it's null, but I wonder if there is a better way to determine this.

Answer (score 3):

It's not totally clear from the question how you're calling your HTTParty request and why you're posting the response object as opposed to the body of the response, which is what I'm assuming you are wanting to check the presence/existence of. You may need a `JSON.parse()` if the response body is a string; or you may need to call a `.body` on the response object itself to get the JSON you're looking for. Perhaps this will help:

```
require 'json'

# your_request = however you're calling your API w/HTTParty
JSON.parse(your_request.body) == {}
```

Hope this helps! :)